# Is there a way I can incorporate g suite services into php?

Tags: google-apps-script

This services like accessing the contents of google drive and sharing to user in my organisation, synchronizing classes in the php system (for school Information management system)with google classroom?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [beta client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/) for PHP to access the Google APIs.

You could access Google Apps Scripts by utilising the [Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api), though no specific examples are provided for doing so from PHP.